# Prove $\left|\begin{smallmatrix} \sin^2x&\cot x&1\\ \sin^2y&\cot y&1\\ \sin^2z&\cot z&1 \end{smallmatrix}\right|=0$ if $x+y+z=\pi$

Tags: matrices, determinant, triangles

If $x, y, z$ are the angles of $\Delta ABC$, then evaluate

> $$
> \Delta=\begin{vmatrix}
> \sin^2x&\cot x&1\\
> \sin^2y&\cot y&1\\
> \sin^2z&\cot z&1
> \end{vmatrix}=\quad\color{red}{?}
> $$

**My Attempt**

$$
\Delta=\frac{1}{\sin x\sin y\sin z}\begin{vmatrix}
\sin^3x&\cos x&\sin x\\
\sin^3y&\cos y&\sin y\\
\sin^3z&\cos z&\sin z
\end{vmatrix}=
$$
How do I proceed further and prove that the determinant is zero ?

Comment: @ChoF thnx for mentioning. I dont know how you found it. its hard to search for similar questions on matrices and determinants.

Comment: @ss1729 I just checked the **Related** section on the right. I agree that it's hard to search a similar question. It's not your fault.